Modernish books on Gita, Vedas/Upanishads for tweens/teens
Are there any modern books based on ancient Hindu texts suitable for children? I am looking for books that can answer questions about life and introduce spirituality to a child.
Some books I've found were rather dry. I had better luck with playful interpretations like "The Broken Tusk" and "Ramayana: An Illustrated Retelling".
What books do you know of that are lively and bring the Gita/Vedas/Upanishads alive for tween/teen children?
Thank you!

According to the site's rules, one cannot ask for personal advice. So I edited your question and made it a general question. It is a good question.

I'm not sure if it's still a thing, but I wonder if the Amar Chitra Katha are still available. They were basically comic books covering a broad subset of epics and local myths

@JourneymanGeek I found them online, but the sets are expensive.


Eternal Stories from the Upanishads by Thomas Egenes, Kumuda Reddy
Upanishadic Stories by Swami Tattwananda
Stories from Vedanta by Amarananda Swami
Galpe Vedanta by Swami Vishwashrayananda (Bengali)
The Panchatantra by Arthur W. Ryder
Stories from the Bhagavatam by Swami Bodhasarananda

